# When combining tr with null characters and xargs -0, it doesn't work as expected

Tags: bash, awk, xargs, tr

So, I have a file that contains `~` delimited fields that I need to convert to sql. The catch here is that there are spaces in this data. Generally, this wouldn't be an issue because I could just use `xargs -0` and feed it null delimiters.

When I pair it with `tr '~' '\0000'` I get weird behavior and I am not sure why. It seems to actually take too many fields when using xargs.

Input:

```
FA_PRD01_PHX1~EBDT~30-JAN-2023~18~JobDefinition://company/apps/ess/custom/Shared Folders/Apps_Reports/APPSSALESFORCETIMEDTLS~1~1
FA_PRD01_PHX1~EBDT~30-JAN-2023~08~JobDefinition://company/apps/ess/custom/Shared Folders/Apps_Reports/APPSSALESFORCETIMEDTLSNEW~1~1
FA_PRD01_PHX1~EBDT~23-JAN-2023~18~JobDefinition://company/apps/ess/custom/Shared Folders/Apps_Reports/APPSSALESFORCETIMEDTLS~1~1
FA_PRD01_PHX1~EBDT~23-JAN-2023~08~JobDefinition://company/apps/ess/custom/Shared Folders/Apps_Reports/APPSSALESFORCETIMEDTLSNEW~1~1
FA_PRD01_PHX1~EBDT~13-MAR-2023~04~JobDefinition://company/apps/ess/custom/shared/Apps_Reports/Certifications and Competencies/ALLCERTRPT~1~1
FA_PRD01_PHX1~EBDT~13-FEB-2023~18~JobDefinition://company/apps/ess/custom/Shared Folders/Apps_Reports/APPSSALESFORCETIMEDTLS~1~1
FA_PRD01_PHX1~EBDT~13-FEB-2023~08~JobDefinition://company/apps/ess/custom/Shared Folders/Apps_Reports/APPSSALESFORCETIMEDTLSNEW~1~1
FA_PRD01_PHX1~EBDT~13-FEB-2023~05~JobDefinition://company/apps/ess/custom/shared/Apps_Reports/Certifications and Competencies/ALLCERTRPT~1~1
FA_PRD01_PHX1~EBDT~06-FEB-2023~18~JobDefinition://company/apps/ess/custom/Shared Folders/Apps_Reports/APPSSALESFORCETIMEDTLS~1~1
FA_PRD01_PHX1~EBDT~06-FEB-2023~08~JobDefinition://company/apps/ess/custom/Shared Folders/Apps_Reports/APPSSALESFORCETIMEDTLSNEW~1~1
```

command:

```bash
cat data.txt | tr '~' '\0000' | 
   xargs -0 -n 7 printf "insert into ESS_SYSTEM_ERROR_METRICS  values('%s','%s',to_date('%s','DD-MM-YYYY'),%s,'%s',%s,%s);\n"
```

expected:

```
insert into ESS_SYSTEM_ERROR_METRICS  values('FA_PRD01_PHX1','EBDT',to_date('30-JAN-2023','DD-MM-YYYY'),18,'JobDefinition://company/apps/ess/custom/Shared Folders/Apps_Reports/APPSSALESFORCETIMEDTLS',1,1);
```

actual:

```
insert into ESS_SYSTEM_ERROR_METRICS  values('FA_PRD01_PHX1','EBDT',to_date('30-JAN-2023','DD-MM-YYYY'),18,'JobDefinition://company/apps/ess/custom/Shared Folders/Apps_Reports/APPSSALESFORCETIMEDTLS',1,1
FA_PRD01_PHX1);
insert into ESS_SYSTEM_ERROR_METRICS  values('EBDT','30-JAN-2023',to_date('08','DD-MM-YYYY'),JobDefinition://company/apps/ess/custom/Shared Folders/Apps_Reports/APPSSALESFORCETIMEDTLSNEW,'1',1
FA_PRD01_PHX1,EBDT);
```

My field count with xargs is correct, so I am also wondering if xargs is using something else to delimit.

Comment: use `awk -F~ '{printf("insert ... %s.....%s\n", $1, $2... $7)'` instead? (no need for `xargs` either(?) Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're replacing the `~` with a `\0` character and using the `\0` as delimiter for `xargs`, the `\n` in the input will be treated as part of the last "field"; you need to translate the newlines in the input too:

```
tr '\n~' '\0' < data.txt |
xargs -0 -n 7 printf "insert into ESS_SYSTEM_ERROR_METRICS  values('%s','%s',to_date('%s','DD-MM-YYYY'),%s,'%s',%s,%s);\n"
```

**advice:** When generating code automatically, you better make sure to escape the strings properly (here you print them RAW, that might prove dangerous)

---

##### UPDATE

By proper escaping I mean generating the SQL in a way that won't allow code-injection; for example:

```bash
awk -F'~' '
    function sql_stringify(str,escape_backslashes) {
        gsub(/\047/,"\047\047",str);
        if (escape_backslashes)
            gsub(/\\/,"\\\\&",str);
        return "\047" str "\047";
    }
    {
        printf( "insert into ESS_SYSTEM_ERROR_METRICS  " );
        printf( "values(%s,%s,to_date(%s,%s),%d,%s,%d,%d);\n", \
            sql_stringify($1), \
            sql_stringify($2), \
            sql_stringify($3), \
            sql_stringify("DD-MM-YYYY"), \
            $4, \
            sql_stringify($5), \
            $6, \
            $7 \
       );
    }
' data.txt
```

<sup>**note:** for MySQL and PostgreSQL you'll need to set the `escape_backslashes` switch of `sql_stringify` to true</sup>

Comment: I decided to use `%s` instead of `%d` because printf think that `09` is to be interpreted as octal.

Answer (score 4):

Since `xargs` is looking at `\0` as a delimiter, the `\n` becomes part of the data.  Ideally we need to convert the `\n` to `\0`, too.  Alternatively ...

We can keep the `~` delimiter and convert the `\n` to `~`:

```
$ head -2 data.txt | tr '\n' '~' | xargs -d~ -n 7 printf "insert into ESS_SYSTEM_ERROR_METRICS  values('%s','%s',to_date('%s','DD-MM-YYYY'),%s,'%s',%s,%s);\n"
insert into ESS_SYSTEM_ERROR_METRICS  values('FA_PRD01_PHX1','EBDT',to_date('30-JAN-2023','DD-MM-YYYY'),18,'JobDefinition://company/apps/ess/custom/Shared Folders/Apps_Reports/APPSSALESFORCETIMEDTLS',1,1);
insert into ESS_SYSTEM_ERROR_METRICS  values('FA_PRD01_PHX1','EBDT',to_date('30-JAN-2023','DD-MM-YYYY'),08,'JobDefinition://company/apps/ess/custom/Shared Folders/Apps_Reports/APPSSALESFORCETIMEDTLSNEW',1,1);
```

---

An alternative idea using `awk`:

```
$ awk -F'~' -v qt="'" '{printf "insert into ESS_SYSTEM_ERROR_METRICS  values(%s,%s,to_date(%s,%s),%s,%s,%s,%s);\n",qt $1 qt,qt $2 qt,qt $3 qt,qt "DD-MM-YYYY" qt, $4,qt $5 qt,$6,$7 }' data.txt
insert into ESS_SYSTEM_ERROR_METRICS  values('FA_PRD01_PHX1','EBDT',to_date('30-JAN-2023','DD-MM-YYYY'),18,'JobDefinition://company/apps/ess/custom/Shared Folders/Apps_Reports/APPSSALESFORCETIMEDTLS',1,1);
insert into ESS_SYSTEM_ERROR_METRICS  values('FA_PRD01_PHX1','EBDT',to_date('30-JAN-2023','DD-MM-YYYY'),08,'JobDefinition://company/apps/ess/custom/Shared Folders/Apps_Reports/APPSSALESFORCETIMEDTLSNEW',1,1);
... snip ...
```

Granted, a bit of overkill for this particular case but something to keep in mind if/when you find yourself with some tricky formatting issues that are hard(er) to handle with just `tr/xargs`, ymmv ...

Comment: `xargs -d` isn't well supported

Comment: `-d` isn't supported on y mac.

Comment: I didn't know that xargs would still use `\n` as a delimiter if I told it `-0`, that was my mistake

Answer (score 1):

`xargs` is using a null byte to delimit, like you told it to. It isn't delimiting on newlines.

In a very stripped down example, if you have these two lines (where `0` is a null):

```
a0b0c0d\n
e0f0g0h\n
```

The fourth token is not just `d`, it's `d\ne` because `xargs` reads all the way until the next null byte.

Something like this should work:

```
while IFS='~' read -ra line ; do
  printf '%s\0' "${line[@]}"
done < data.txt | xargs -0 -n 7 printf "insert into ESS_SYSTEM_ERROR_METRICS  values('%s','%s',to_date('%s','DD-MM-YYYY'),%s,'%s',%s,%s);\n"
```

Comment: no need for the `\0` + `xargs` in this case; could feed the array directly to the desired `printf` inside the loop: `while IFS='~' read -ra line; do printf "insert into ...." "${line[@]}"; done < data.txt`